# How to find $U+W$ and $U\cap W$ based on the following assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in R^4\mid x_1+ x_2=0, x_3+ x_4=0 \}$, $W=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in R^4\mid x_1+ x_3=0, x_2+ x_4=0 \}$, how to find $U+W$ and $U\cap W$?

I think $U\cap W=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in R^4\mid x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4 \}$

But I don't know how to express $U+W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the conditions systematically.
I.e. $x_1+x_2 = 0 \Rightarrow x_1 = -x_2$, $x_3+x_4=0 \Rightarrow x_3=-x_4$. From this, note that any vector $u \in U$ can be written in the form $(a,-a, b, -b)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Do the same to write some arbitrary $w \in W$.

Then take your arbitrary $u,w$ and compute $u+w$. This should be the conditions for a vector to be in $U+W$.

Then compare the terms for a vector to be in both $U$ and $W$.

Comment: so $w$ can be expressed as $c, d, -c, -d$. $u+w$ can be expressed as $a+c, d-a, b-c, -(b+d) $. But I still can't see the pattern. And what is $U\cap W$ here?

Comment: Sorry, I think that's right. For $U \cap W$, any $w \in W$ can be written as $(c,d,-c,-d)$, so combining this with the conditions above it must be that for $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) \in U \cap W$, it must be that $v_1=-v_2$, $v_3=-v_4$, $v_1=-v_3$, and $v_2=-v_4$.

Comment: To simplify $U+W$, let $v_1=a+c, v_2=d-a, v_3=b-c$. Then notice that $v_4$ can be written as a linear combination of those three, namely $v_4=-(v_1+v_2+v_3)$. So any vector in $U+W$ can be written as $(v_1,v_2,v_3,-(v_1+v_2+v_3))$.